# Combination problem . Can't find my mistake .. i have checked for repetition can't find any

Tags: combinatorics

The total number of six-digit natural numbers that can be made with the digits 1, 2, 3, 4, if all digits are to appear in the same number at least once is

My approach=
Out of the 6 places I will choose any four , (6C4) ways to do this .
Now I will fill the numbers 1,2,3,4 without any repetition in the 4 places chosen . 4! Ways to do so .. now ways to fill each of  my remaining places are 4 as all 4 numbers are available.. so the total ways should be
6C4 * 4! * 4 * 4

But my answer is not matching .. where am I going wrong ?

Comment: Think about 123444.  The places to place 1234 could be 1234__, 123_4_, or 123__4.

Comment: What exactly did you mean by checking  for repetition?

Comment: The value $\binom644!4^2=5760$ exceeds $4^6=4096$, which is a sure sign you are over-counting something.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that for any number, there may be multiple ways to choose the four places to fill in the four numbers $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$.  In particular, for any of the duplicates, you have an alternate choice of positions by swapping one of those in.

Hints: There are many approaches to this problem, here are two ideas.

1. There are two different types of numbers.  Ones with two numbers repeated and ones with one number in triplicate.  For each of these types, you can count the number of ways that they can appear.
2. You can use a large inclusion-exclusion approach to take all numbers with the digits $1,2,3,4$ and subtract the numbers involving three of these digits.

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental point you are missing is that in counting a number of configurations by devising a procedure for selecting one and then counting the number of ways in which it can proceed (which is what you do), there are *two* things to check. First is that all configurations can be obtained by the procedure; this one is usually the main goal one has in mind so it is not easily overlooked. But the other thing to check is that each choice in the selection procedure can be reconstructed from its outcome (the configuration produced); if this fails there will be more than one run of the procedure that produces the same outcome, so counting ways for the procedure will over-count the configurations. In your case you start with selecting a subset of positions that will ensure presence of all $4$ numbers, but this subset cannot be reconstructed from the final outcome (the six-digit number): any subset with the property that the number has distinct digits on those positions will do, and for any given number there will be more than one such subset. It would have sufficed that for *some* outcomes (numbers) there are multiple subsets to see that the method is flawed.

As a general indication, when a problem statement says *at least one* then one could interpret that as *not zero*, which is a hint that inclusion/exclusion might be a good approach.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you chose the first four places in your initial pick, and filled them as 1 2 3 4, then you could put 1 in the fifth place and 2 in the sixth; OR, you could pick the last four places in your initial pick and filled them as 3 4 1 2, then put 1 in the first place and 2 in the second - you have chosen the same number twice.

You could proceed instead by counting numbers where two digits are used twice each and, separately, those where one digit is used three times.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @Michael Burr has explained why your analysis is incorrect.

There are $4^6$ possible $6$-digit numbers without constraint.

Given any $3$ digits from $\{ 1, 2, 3, 4 \}$, there are $3^6$ possible $6$-digit numbers that are limited to the $3$ selected digits, so subtract $4 \cdot 3^6$ from the above number.

But this overcounts numbers that omit $2$ or $3$ digits.  Use the principle of inclusion and exclusion.

Your answer will be $4^6 - 4 \cdot 3^6 + \binom 42 \cdot 2^6 - 4 = 1560$.

Answer (score 0):

Use

$$\sum_{k=0}^4 (-1)^k\binom{4}{k} (4-k)^6$$

which is the inclusion-exclusion principle for this example.

Or $$4\times\frac{6!}{3!} + 6\times\frac{6!}{2!2!} = 480 + 1080 = 1560$$

which is the number of patterns of $111234$ and $112234$ respectively.